# Discord.py run event if a channel is created in category

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm currently working on a bot which notifies me per message when a new ticket is created.
But because we also have VoiceMaster (a bot which lets you create your own voice channel) I only want the event to trigger when a channel is created in a specific category and I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the category object `category`, then this should work.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if channel.category == category:
        #run
```

If you also want to test for if it's a voice channel, you could change the if to this.

```
if channel.category == category and type(channel) == discord.VoiceChannel:
```